# Two PHP foreaches causing repeating of rows

Tags: php, cakephp

Hey guys, I have a bit of a problem and it's been frustrating me to no end. I've got a CakePHP application that I've been working on, and I can't seem to find a way to display things the way that I'd like to.

This is the code in my controller method:

```
function index(){
    $this->Order->recursive = 2;
    $orders = $this->Order->findAllByVendor_id($this->Auth->User('vendor_id'));
    foreach($orders as $order){
        $item_ids = explode(',', $order['Order']['items']);
        foreach($item_ids as $item_id){
            $products = $this->Product->findById($item_id);
            $order_products[] = $products['Product']['product_name'];
        }
        $vendor_orders[] = $order_products;
    }
    $this->set('orders_products', $vendor_orders);
    $this->set('orders', $this->paginate('Order', array('Order.vendor_id' => $this->Auth->User('vendor_id'))));
}
```

This is my view code:

```
<div class="block" id="vendor-dash">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <?php
        $i = 0;
        foreach($orders as $order){
            $class = null;
            if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
                $class = ' class="altrow"';
            }

            $pickup_time=date("H:i", strtotime($order['Order']['pickup_time']));
            $difference = strtotime('23:52') - date('H:i');
            // echo date("H:i", strtotime($difference));
            foreach($orders_products as $order_products){
        ?>
        <tr<?php echo $class;?> id="<?php echo $order['Order']['id']; ?>">
            <td class="confirmation"><?php echo $order['Order']['confirmation']; ?></td>
            <td class="products">
            <?php 
                    foreach($order_products as $order_product){
                        echo $order_product . ', ';
                    }
            ?></td>
            <td><a href="#" id="<?php echo $order['Order']['id']; ?>" class="action">Fulfill Order</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php    
                } 
        } ?>
</div>
```

Both the foreach($orders as $order) and the foreach($orders_products as $order_products) are holding info for multiple orders. $orders hold the order number, pickup time, etc. while $orders_products is the array of arrays created in the controller (above) by "exploding" an array of product ID's that is stored in a database field for each order (e.g. 1,2,3).

Whenever the page is brought up, however, it displays each order three times because of the two foreach loops that run one time for each order. so instead of three orders with a few items each, I end up seeing nine orders.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you seeing the expected number of "order products" with each order?  Or multiples of those?

Comment: yes. the correct number of order products are appearing, each order is just showing up three times (a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c) because i have the two foreach loops. any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in your `index` method that you're not setting `$order_products` to an empty array before looping back over the `$item_ids` -- try something like this:

```
function index(){
    $this->Order->recursive = 2;
    $orders = $this->Order->findAllByVendor_id($this->Auth->User('vendor_id'));
    foreach($orders as $order){
        $order_products = array(); // Here is the reset to an empty array.
        $item_ids = explode(',', $order['Order']['items']);
        foreach($item_ids as $item_id){
            $products = $this->Product->findById($item_id);
            $order_products[] = $products['Product']['product_name'];
        }
        $vendor_orders[] = $order_products;
    }
    $this->set('orders_products', $vendor_orders);
    $this->set('orders', $this->paginate('Order', array('Order.vendor_id' => $this->Auth->User('vendor_id'))));
}
```

Comment: You also may want to create a `HABTM` between the `Order` and a `Product` so that you don't have to do that comma separated list.

Comment: Looking up how to setup  HABTM. I'm new to Cake, so it probably wasn't the best choice of technology for a time-intensive project, but hey, gotta learn somehow, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

Array overgrowth.  In the controller, the **$order_products** array grows with each loop.

So, reset the array within `foreach ($orders as $order)`:

```
foreach($orders as $order){
    $item_ids = explode(',', $order['Order']['items']);

    $order_products = array();  // <-- RESET ARRAY

    foreach($item_ids as $item_id){
        $products = $this->Product->findById($item_id);
        $order_products[] = $products['Product']['product_name'];
    }
    $vendor_orders[] = $order_products;
}
```

and, something looks odd in the view... checking

...extra foreach loop after

```
  //echo date("H:i", strtotime($difference));
  foreach($orders_products as $order_products){  // <--  EXTRA. comment it out and it's }
```

HOWEVER, I still don't see how you're getting the right products with the right order.

Comment: Replaced the controller code with what you provided, but still repeats orders. Must be something in the view?

Comment: new suggestions for view added.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't fix it right away, but I think I'm on the right track now. :)